# find all duplicates values in multi dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array as following

```
array(
  0 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'abc'),
  1 => array('email' => 'xyz@abc.com','name'=>'xyz'),
  2 => array('email' => 'uvw@abc.com','name'=>'uvw'),
  3 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'str'),
 )
```

I want to filter out records on email address and get records having same email address. For example from above example I want

```
 array(
  0 => array(
     array(
         0 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'abc'),
         1 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'str'),
     )
 )
```

My code is

```
 $tmpArray = array();
    $duplicateRecords = array();
    if (empty($data)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if (in_array($value['Email'], $tmpArray)) {
            $duplicateRecords[] = $value;
        }
        $tmpArray[] = $value['Email'];
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r($duplicateRecords);die;
```

But this piece of code only returns the record's once existance, which is of second time. I know when It is traversing first time it isn't having email to compare. Is there any way to get existence of record as many times as it is in array.

Comment: So you want to group the elements of your array, themselves arrays, by the value of their "email" key.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes I want to group array elements having same email id

Answer (score 1):

```
// get count of each email
$counters = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'email'));

// collect email with counter > 1
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($counters[$item['email']] > 1) {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_column` available since php5.5

Comment: @Vleonov, Hi I have updated my question regards resultant array format. If I want resultant array like `array(
      0 => array(
         array(
             0 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'abc'),
             1 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'str'),
         )
     )` to have multiple values?

Comment: @AwaisQarni, then do this: $result[$item['email'][] = $item;
It will group array by email, as you wish

Answer (score 1):

This one should work for you:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($key < $k && $value['email'] == $v['email']) {
            $result[] = array(
                $value,
                $v
            );
        }
    }
}
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8trq-k2zc

Please note: this would only find you the conflicting pairs. For example:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'email' => 'abc@abc.com',
        'name' => 'abc'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'abc@abc.com',
        'name' => 'def'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'abc@abc.com',
        'name' => 'ghi'
    )
);
```

Would result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => abc
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => def
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => abc
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => ghi
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => def
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => ghi
                )

        )

)
```

So `abc` conflicts with `def`, `abc` conflicts with `ghi`, and `def` conflicts with `ghi`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'two pass' solution. The code is commented.

PHP 5.3.18

```
<?php // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548634/find-all-duplicates-values-in-multi-dimensional-array-php

$data = array(
  0 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'abc'),
  1 => array('email' => 'xyz@abc.com','name'=>'xyz'),
  2 => array('email' => 'uvw@abc.com','name'=>'uvw'),
  3 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'str'),
 );

// two passes required

// first pass: count of emails
$emailCounts = array();

foreach($data as $emailEntry) {
    if (isset($emailCounts[$emailEntry['email']])) {
        $emailCounts[$emailEntry['email']] += 1;
    }
    else {
        $emailCounts[$emailEntry['email']] = 1;
    }
}

// second pass: extract duplicate emails (count > 1)
$duplicateEmails = array();

foreach($data as $emailEntry) {
    if ($emailCounts[$emailEntry['email']] > 1) {
       $duplicateEmails[] = $emailEntry;
    }
}

// show output...
var_dump($emailCounts);

var_dump($duplicateEmails);
```

Actual output:

```
array
  'abc@abc.com' => int 2
  'xyz@abc.com' => int 1
  'uvw@abc.com' => int 1

array
  0 => 
    array
      'email' => string 'abc@abc.com' (length=11)
      'name' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array
      'email' => string 'abc@abc.com' (length=11)
      'name' => string 'str' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code for you
>$mainarray=array(
  0 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'abc'),
 1 => array('email' => 'xyz@abc.com','name'=>'xyz'),
 2 => array('email' => 'uvw@abc.com','name'=>'uvw'),
 3 => array('email' => 'abc@abc.com','name'=>'str'),
 );

foreach($mainarray as $single){
$emailarray[]=$single['email'];
}
foreach(array_count_values($emailarray) as $val => $c)
   if($c > 1) $dups[] = $val;

foreach($mainarray as $single){
    if(in_array($single['email'], $dups)){
        $result[]=$single;
    }
}
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```